# Is there any chance of this code printing null?

Tags: java, swing, applet, null, nullpointerexception

```
String readwidget(int a, int b){     

    WidgetChild readwidget = Widgets.get(a,b);            
    if(readwidget.getText() != null){         
        Task.sleep(10);
        System.out.println(readwidget.getText());
        return readwidget.getText();
    }

    Task.sleep(10);
    return    GOT_NULL; 

}

while(readFirstWidget.equals(GOT_NULL) && t5.isRunning()) {     

    readFirstWidget = readwidget(1184, 13);
    Task.sleep(50,80);

}
```

This piece of code is crashing with nullpointerexception once in while(1 out of 50 time) and it prints null at that point of time which it should not. Can anyone please help me to find out the causes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?  Could `Widgets.get(a,b);` be returning null?

Comment: yes, it can return null.

Comment: what does the read widget.getText() do? It seems as if it can go from null to a non null String, but then you read three times. Can it ever go back to null again?

Comment: @Roger : Thanks a lot. i got one important programming lesson today. I will change the code, and check if it solves the prob.

Comment: Well, if `Widgets.get(a,b)` can return `null`, then you need to *check the return value for `null`*, rather than just using it immediately on the next line. (You check `readWidget.getText()` for `null`, but if `readWidget` itself is `null`, then you're going to crash.)

Comment: @dlev You could post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention in a comment that `Widgets.get(a,b)` can return `null`. Given that, you need to guard against that possibility by checking the return value from the method for `null` prior to actually calling any instance methods on it. You aren't doing that, and so you are crashing in that case.

All you need to do is add the null check and your code should be fine:

```
WidgetChild readwidget = Widgets.get(a,b);            
if(readwidget != null && readwidget.getText() != null) {
```

Comment: I modified the code and and checked for null at both the places, and also I stored the value of readwidget.getText() in a string variable. It solved the prob. Thank you.